# IOS rejection because a web page inan app contains a dial href

Tags: ios

This was the error:

Specifically, when user presses police button or phone button on bottom menu no further action is produced. Also, the "call city hall" option resolves to a blank screen.

Is there a sniffer I can code in to allow the app browser to know the difference between phone capable (dial capable) and not dial capable devices?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you just need to check if the device can open "tel" URLs:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]];
```